# How to make Scrollable Label in NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, scrollbar, ngui

I want to make a Scrollable Label in NGUI. Suppose there is list of name of producer, programmer, artiest and other stuff in Label. and there is also scroll bar when i pull up and down. It will show list of contents in Scrollable View.
I searched in internet but i did not get idea how access label height and how to put in scroll bar and how to make clipping rectangle.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version is your NGUI?

Comment: I am using NGUI v3.5.4r2

Comment: NGUI comes with tons of examples. Even with scrollable content demos. Please do have a look at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [UIScrollView](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_scroll_view.html) component. It is used together with `UIPanel` to provide scrollable, clipped content. Usually it is used also with `UIGrid` or `UITable`, to provide functionality of scrolled table.

However in your case you should just create all your Credits content as a child of this UIScrollView. If you want, you can add another `GameObject` with `UIScrollBar` to provide scroll bar functionality.

If you take a closer look on imported `NGUI` package, you will find various Example scenes, where such functionality is used. Also this official tutorial may help: [UIScrollView tutorial](http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=6763.0).